# rails web config folder does not have the webpack folder eventhough I setup the foder without error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, webpack

here is my problem.

I setup a very simple website by rails command and here is my command

rails new freelancer --database=postgresql

and I meet no error

I used postgre sql and postico to test the database and saw the database.

In the file database.yml, there are 2 databases and I ran this command

```
rails db:setup
rails db:migrate
```

In postgre sql I also saw the database, maybe it is ok.

But my problem is, I do not see the folder webpack as the tutorial, the folder webpack must like this : (folder) freelancer > (folder) config > (folder) webpack

But I do not see it.

Must I run this command ? To create this folder ?

```
rails webpacker:install
```

Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Gemfile file, there should be the gem 'webpacker', just run 'bundle install' for installing all the gems that will be used in the project.

If you dont have that one in the Gemfile, just add it like:

```
gem 'webpacker'
```

Then it should all be done, but if you still not see the folder, use the command you are saying:

```
rails webpacker:install
```