# rails problem : The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails

as the title, I meet this problem, and here is what I did.

I created the rails program by this command

```
rails new freelancer --database=postgresql --javascript=webpack
```

And I followed the tutorial, when I met the problem is I did now see the webpack folder, I solved this problem by followed the command in this link

[rails web config folder does not have the webpack folder eventhough I setup the foder without error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74507472/rails-web-config-folder-does-not-have-the-webpack-folder-eventhough-i-setup-the/74507741#74507741)

Then I ran this command to make a page

```
Rails g controller Pages home
```

In this folder app -> views -> layouts there are 3 files application.html.erb, mailer.html.erb, mailer.text.erb then maybe my work is ok ?

Then, I add some code from the page bulma.com to the file application.html.erb

Then I start the server by this command

```
rails s
```

and go to the link

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/home
```

It said to me that there was an error

```
The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

The error at here

```
Showing .../Desktop/Rails/freelancer/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

So what I need to do do solve this problem ? Could you please give me some advice for this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `bin/dev` to start the server and webpack

Comment: @Alex thanks for your comment, but I still do not understand your comment, what do you mean bin/dev ? You mean I must run this command instead of rails s ?

Comment: correct, it is just an executable. it starts the server and runs webpack command to compile application.js. you can add or change these in `Procfile.dev` file.

Comment: @Alex : thank you very much. But after using your command, I still got the error, just changing to another one : Extracted source (around line #10): <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
So, what I must do to fix this one ?

Comment: well, I'm not sure. I tried all the steps you described and it works fine. from the linked question you've installed `webpacker` which is obsolete. whatever tutorial you're following seems outdated. take a look at `shakapacker` as alternative. rails 7 uses `jsbundling-rails` for all this. you might be missing `//= link_tree ../builds` from `app/assets/config/manifest.js` and make sure webpack actually compiles without any errors.

Comment: @Alex thanks for your comment, here is my code, could you please take a look at my code for some minutes ? https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/freelancer

Comment: `webpacker` and `jsbundling-rails` do the same thing and you have both installed. just run `bin/rails javascript:install:webpack`. then `bin/dev` should be working. or better start with a fresh app, don't use webpacker.